# Unable to SSH with newly created user - deployer@IP_ADRS: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I've tried various solutions out there, but I still have a problem to SSH into my server with newly created username.

To SSH into server, usually I've used userAdmin@IP_ADRS, it worked without having to provide a password, by registering my local machine SSH key in server's SSH settings page (using digitalocean droplet).

If I generate a new user, it simply does not allow me to login, showing me an error:

`deployer@IP_ADRS: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic)`

Here is my config:

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin no
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin yes
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

Could anyone notice what is wrong with my configuration ?

#### UPDATED

Doing `ssh -v deployer@server_ip` output following:

```
user@local:~/$ ssh -v deployer@CENSORED_SERVER_IP
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to CENSORED_SERVER_IP [CENSORED_SERVER_IP] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to CENSORED_SERVER_IP:22 as 'deployer'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:R/y/sJgyq4XwBUM3xqwF4l/jKS7lq60y39CUmzvmQAw
debug1: Host 'CENSORED_SERVER_IP' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:kBwWWIMbsDO14TrQ+TUrKGCPAd7T8lytuGDzFFP81F4
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:GWaslmtwWDw2gzXtdUVtk6fClTDsxSy3NS/EqwBhVZM
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)


debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:kBwWWIMbsDO14TrQ+TUrKGCPAd7T8lytuGDzFFP81F4
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:GWaslmtwWDw2gzXtdUVtk6fClTDsxSy3NS/EqwBhVZM
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
deployer@CENSORED_SERVER_IP: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: Are you connecting to the correct server? Do the server's system logs show _any_ mention of your connection attempt?

Comment: sure, it's the same IP I'm using to connect with my first user I've created upon the ubuntu installation.
That's what I get from a log: `Jun  3 08:35:10 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-25gb-ams3-01 sshd[52308]: Connection closed by authenticating user deployer MY_LOCAL_IP port 65418 [preauth]`

Comment: Ok, in that case what happens if you connect with `ssh -v` **and** add `LogLevel VERBOSE` to the sshd_config (and restart sshd), or if that doesn't help, then `LogLevel DEBUG`? Both the client and the server should start logging a bit more.

Comment: @user1686 - I've updated my post with an output of `ssh -v`

Comment: In this case, `ssh -v` says it _is_ offering the keys in id_rsa and id_ed25519 (assuming that's the right key?), so you really need to check the server's logs instead to find out why it's not accepting them.

Comment: Find the working users SSH public key location on the server, provide us the location of the key, why didn’t you add the key for the additional users through the web interface?

Comment: The problem was coming from `Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf` which is defined in the configuration, where the was a param `PasswordAuthentication` set to `no`. At first I believed it's overriden by order